# Как сделать чтобы InputStream принимал данные в фоновом режиме

Tags: java, android

Ни как не могу понять как лучше сделать, решил написать сюда.

Нужно сделать так чтобы InputStream принимал данные в фоновом режиме. Тобишь если данные есть то он их высчитывает и ждет дальше. Не закрывается!.

Если данных нет то просто ждет, если данные есть то принимает их и дальше ждет.

Как такое провернуть?

Comment: О какой конкретно реализации InputStream речь? В целом контракт таков: если данных, еще нет, но контекст подразумаевает, что они будут (открытый сокет, например) чтение из потока блокируется. Если же данных нет и не предвидится никогда (сокет закрылся, например), то поток вернет -1, и его больше нельзя использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
private static void asyncRead(InputStream inputStream) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Разве while не получит false после того как reader.readLine() станет пустым? и тогда данный поток зароется. А мне надо чтобы поток не закрыался, а был постоянно живым, пока не придется к нему команда допустим off или приложение не закроется

Comment: @xTIGRx все зависит от того, что является источником inputStream. если это файл, то разумеется поток дойдет до конца файла и завершится, если же, это какой то "бесконечный поток", например читающий из сокета, то на операции read будет блокировка и ожидание появления данных.

Comment: слушайте а с чего line должен получить null? он ведь никогда не получит его. Если крах какой нибудь не случиться

Comment: @xTIGRx справедливое замечание, но я не знаю откуда вы там пытаетесь прочесть данные. Если это сокет, то вы должны предусмотреть некий механизм остановки, например передавать какую то последовательность символов, получив которую поток бы завершался.

Comment: Блютуз сокет. Пока есть соединение поток или цикл держиться и ждет данных, данные приходят опять ждет не выключается. Надо так

Comment: Тогда все ок, Данный код, будет висеть и ждать данных на сокете.

Comment: как он определит последнее сообщение? если данные по сокету не придут то операции на чтения блокирует текущий поток и он будет висеть пока они не появятся.

Comment: получается что read() работает по принципу white(true)?

Comment: Он работает по принципу, while(buffer.isEmpty()) Thread.currentThread().sleep(),  но только для "бесконечных" потоков

Comment: А батарею не садит она? также как и while(true)?

Comment: Поток спит, он не расходует cpu